# Can not run rails server for my application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am trying to run a project downloaded from internet, it is ruby on rails, I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
        3: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
        2: from C:/Users/Amira/canvas/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from C:/Users/Amira/canvas/bin/spring:10:in `read'
C:/Users/Amira/canvas/bin/spring:10:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Amira/canvas/Gemfile.lock (Errno::ENOENT)
```

The code written in the file is as following

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This file loads spring without using Bundler, in order to be fast.
# It gets overwritten when you run the `spring binstub` command.

unless defined?(Spring)
  require 'rubygems'
  require 'bundler'

  if (match = Bundler.default_lockfile.read.match(/^GEM$.*?^    (?:  )*spring \((.*?)\)$.*?^$/m))
    Gem.paths = { 'GEM_PATH' => [Bundler.bundle_path.to_s, *Gem.path].uniq.join(Gem.path_separator) }
    gem 'spring', match[1]
    require 'spring/binstub'
  end
end
```

It is an opensource project and I am new on rails
can anyone please help me ?

**EDIT**

Gemfile content

```
# What have they done to the Gemfile???
#
# Relax. Breathe deep. All the gems are still there; they're just loaded in various files in Gemfile.d/
# This allows us to require gems locally that we might not want to commit to our public repo. We can maintain
# a customized list of gems for development and debuggery, without affecting our ability to merge with canvas-lms
#
# NOTE: this file has to use 1.8.7 hash syntax to not raise a parser exception on 1.8.7
#
# NOTE: some files in Gemfile.d/ will have certain required gems indented. While this may seem arbitrary,
# it actually has semantic significance. An indented gem required in Gemfile is a gem that is NOT
# directly used by Canvas, but required by a gem that is used by Canvas. We lock into specific versions of
# these gems to prevent regression, and the indentation serves to alert us to the relationship between the gem and canvas-lms
source 'https://rubygems.org/'


Dir[File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'gems/plugins/*/Gemfile.d/_before.rb')].each do |file|
  eval(File.read(file), nil, file)
end

require File.expand_path("../config/canvas_rails_switcher", __FILE__)

Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'Gemfile.d', '*.rb')).sort.each do |file|
  eval(File.read(file), nil, file)
end
```

Comment: is there a `Gemfile.lock` file in the root of the directory?

Comment: navigate to the root of the project and try and run `bundle install`. You may also need to run `gem install bundler` first

Comment: @RockwellRice there is file called Gemfile but with no extension and I have edit the question with it is content

Comment: @RockwellRice and there is yarn.lock file

Comment: @engineersmnky I did and I got the same error

Comment: you need a `Gemfile.lock` file, Gemfile is different

Answer (score 0):

The `Gemfile` usually specifies the dependencies (other code the application needs). The project you look into seems to use a slightly more complex setup.

Normally it works roughly like this:
Once the dependencies are installed via bundler (the command `bundle` or the more explicit `bundle install`), a `Gemfile.lock` is placed next to it to list the actually used versions of the installed dependencies.

Two takeaways:

1. use `bundle` (the gem is called bundler) to install dependencies.
2. read the README of the project carefully. If it does not have instructions on installation, create an issue if the projects has a method to do so. If you are hypernice or normal and the project is open and healthy, create a Pull Request for the README in which you describe how you managed to install the app.

**Edit** this might have sounded a bit arrogant, and I did not peek into the details. I assume you followed https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms/wiki/Quick-Start . The canvas-lms project uses a setup slightly more complex than your typical Rails application. I believe you should ask specifically for help with canvas installation (edit your question).